# Problems with fetching the response from www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to fetch the answer from

> recapcha/api/siteverify

I generate my url as:

> www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=secret_key&response=g-recaptcha-token

and when I simply visit this URL via my browser it shows me json with `success:true` and correct timestamp and hostname.

So I'm trying to fetch these results:

```
fetch(url).then(
          function(response) {
              window.alert(response.json())
              if (!response.success){
                window.console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                  response.error);
                return;
              }

      // Examine the text in the response
              window.alert("verified!");
          }
      )
```

But that results with

> TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this API has to be called from the server, not the client.

Comment: That's a good point <ashamed>